# NetworkX - allow duplicate nodes

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


G = nx.DiGraph()


def calculate_lists(user_input):
    """ Calculates the number of occurences of certain character in a string."""
    input_list = []
    for i in user_input:
        input_list.append(i)

    occurence_list = []
    for i in set(input_list):
        occurence_list.append((i, user_input.count(i)))

    sorted_by_first = sorted(occurence_list, key=lambda tup: tup[1])
    sorted_list = list(reversed(sorted_by_first))

    propability_list = []
    for i in range(len(sorted_list)):
        propability_list.append(sorted_list[i][1])

    print("Input list is: ", input_list)
    print("Input list is: ", input_list)
    print("Occurence list: ", occurence_list)
    print("Sorted list is: ", sorted_list)
    print("Probility list is: ", propability_list)
    return huffmann_algorithm(propability_list)


def huffmann_algorithm(prob_list):
    node_list = []
    while len(prob_list) != 1:
        first_minimum = min(float(s) for s in prob_list)
        print("First minimum", first_minimum)
        prob_list.remove(first_minimum)
        second_minimum = min(float(s) for s in prob_list)
        print("Second minimum", second_minimum)
        prob_list.remove(second_minimum)
        node_list.append([first_minimum, second_minimum])
        print("new value: ", first_minimum+second_minimum)
        new_value = int(first_minimum+second_minimum)
        prob_list.append(new_value)
    print("Finished: ", prob_list)
    count = 0
    for i in node_list:
        print(count)
        print("Nodes: ", tuple(i))
        G.add_node(i[0])
        G.add_node(i[1])
        G.add_node(i[0]+i[1])
        G.add_edge(i[0], i[0]+i[1])
        G.add_edge(i[1], i[0]+i[1])
    print("Node list: ", node_list)
    print(G.nodes())
    nx.draw_networkx(G, with_labels=True, arrows=False)
    plt.savefig("graph1.png")
    plt.show()


def main():
    user_input = str(input("Please enter a text: "))
    calculate_lists(user_input)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I'm trying to implement a version of the huffman code in python. However, Im not able to add duplicate nodes to the graph. Is there a workaround to display values with the same text? To see what I mean, enter for example: aaaaabbbbcccdde
The graph only shows one node with the label 3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are mistaking nodes with node labels. Having duplicate nodes in a graph doesn't really make sense. What I feel you need here is to have duplicate labels.

What you can do to add the notion of labels to your graph is to have a dictionary that maps nodes identifiers (unique) to node labels (possibly not unique):

```py
user_input = "aaaaabbbbcccdde"
# i is the node identifier and l is its corresponding label:
labels = {i: l for i, l in enumerate(user_input)}
nodes = labels.keys()
```

Using these you can construct your graph:

```py
G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_nodes_from(nodes)
```

Then you can, for example, draw it:

```py
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw(G, pos)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos, labels)
```

And of course (probably most importantly), anytime you have a node identifier, say  `node_id`, you can retrieve its label using `labels[node_id]`. What I suggest is to always work with node identifier, then at the very end, when you need to print a result you can translate node identifiers to something readable by a human, ie. node labels.

Depending on the complexity of your code, you may also find useful to attach the labels to the node objects themselves, networkx allows that:

```py
nx.set_node_attributes(G, labels, 'label')
```

You'll then have access to node attributes:

```py
for node_id, u in G.nodes(data=True):
    print(u)
    break
# Or if you have a node_identifier:
node_id = 1
print(G.node[node_id])
```

This would output:

```
{'label': 'a'}
{'label': 'a'}
```